# Convert ROS2 SQLite bag to MCAP format

Tags: ros2, rosbag, mcap

I've got some ROS2 bags in SQLite format that I'd like to convert to MCAP format, but I cannot find any examples or tools that do it. I'd have hoped there would be an obvious option for `ros2 bag convert`, like the `--output-options` YAML's `storage_id:`, but it's not obvious to me what to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this recently with the mcap cli tool built from source https://github.com/foxglove/mcap:

```
sudo apt install golang-go
git clone git@github.com:foxglove/mcap.git
cd mcap/go
make -C cli/mcap build
./cli/mcap/bin/mcap version  # show the binary works
```

After that you need to have all the message definitions of all the messages in the .db3 file available, source the workspace they were built in (e.g. `source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash` works if using `humble` and all of the required messages were apt installed, or `source ~/my_ros2_ws/install/setup.bash` if you had to build some packages with custom messages):

```
source your_ros2_ws/install/setup.bash 
cd directory_with_db3
# I made a symlink to ./mcap/go/cli/mcap/bin/mcap so it is on my PATH
mcap convert foo.db3 foo.mcap
# see that all the messages are there
mcap info foo.mcap
library:   mcap go v1.0.4                                              
profile:   ros2
messages:  834056                                                      
duration:  9m38.219675178s                                             
start:     2022-01-07T12:39:35.007852857-08:00 (1641587975.007852857)  
end:       2022-01-07T12:49:13.227528035-08:00 (1641588553.227528035)  
compression:
    zstd: [1834/1834 chunks] [15.58 GiB/10.90 GiB (30.03%)] [19.31 MiB/sec] 
channels:
...
```

There's an example mcap I made (and also used `mcap filter` to reduce the size) attached to the issue here (and a workaround to related issue with viewing the mcap in plotjuggler): https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler/issues/878

### mcap convert while missing messages

```
...failed to convert file: failed to find schema for novatel_oem7_msgs/msg/BESTVEL: schema not found
```

It exits immediately on encountering an unknown message and leaves behind an mcap file of size 0.

## ros2 bag convert

ros2 bag convert also works (going from https://mcap.dev/guides/getting-started/ros-2#using-ros2-bag-convert), at least with the ros2 bag I built from iron sources:

convert.yaml:

```
output_bags:
  - uri: ros2_output
    storage_id: mcap
    all: true
```

The uri is the output directory the mcap conversion will be stored in, it doesn't look possible to specify it on the command line as with the `mcap` tool.  More possible parameters for the yaml are listed in https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2#converting-bags but not documented.

```
ros2 bag convert -i E-SOLO-FAST-140-170.db3 -o ../../../convert.yaml

closing.

closing.
[INFO] [1698332502.004769814] [rosbag2_storage]: Opened database 'E-SOLO-FAST-140-170.db3' for READ_ONLY.
```

It creates a subdirectory `ros2_output/` with `metadata.yaml` and `ros2_output_0.mcap` (now format `libmcap 0.8.0`), looks to have all the messages in it.

### ros2 bag convert while missing messages

```
ros2 bag convert -i . -o ../../../convert.yaml 
^C[INFO] [1698419071.371486821] [rosbag2_storage]: Opened database './T-MULTI-FAST-EURO.db3' for READ_ONLY.
[WARN] [1698419071.444842070] [ROSBAG2_TRANSPORT]: Topic '/vehicle_3/radar_front/esr_status1' has unknown type 'delphi_esr_msgs/msg/EsrStatus1' . Only topics with known type are supported. Reason: 'package 'delphi_esr_msgs' not found, searching: [/home/lucasw/ros/ros2_iron/install/rqt_bag_plugins, /home/lucasw/ros/ros2_iron/install/rosbag2,
```

In contrast with `mcap` the `ros2 bag convert` converts every message it does understand and skips the rest.

### ros2 bag zstd compression

These compression options can be added to convert.yaml, but the output `.mcap.zstd` file is not readable by the mcap cli tool (while ros2 bag info works with it):

```
    compression_mode: file
    compression_format: zstd
```

This yields mcap files readable by the mcap tool but the files are a little larger, appears to be the same as the default settings of the mcap cli tool:

```
    compression_mode: message
    compression_format: zstd
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a guide on the MCAP website [here](https://mcap.dev/guides/getting-started/ros-2#using-ros2-bag-convert):

```
$ cat << EOF > convert.yaml
output_bags:
  - uri: ros2_output
    storage_id: mcap
    all: true
EOF
$ ros2 bag convert -i ros2_input.db3 -o convert.yaml
```

If you have the [rosbag2_storage_mcap](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/tree/humble/rosbag2_storage_mcap) package installed, this should work out of the box.